# Android: Several orderBy statements

Tags: android, sql-order-by

Is it possible to make two orderBy statements in one query. Say i wanna order my data after column 1 and afterwards after column 2. What would be the best way to do that?

Sincerely
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just say `ORDER BY Column1, Column2`. If you are using the *orderBy* argument of one of the `query` methods, then remove the prefixing `ORDER BY` as it is inserted for you when building the query.